# Pattern(s) to avoid mutual recursion between functions and other objects?

Tags: .net, recursion, f#

I'm starting to write a toy command line datastore for fun. I am currently storing all of my interpreter's commands in a map which maps the string name of the command as the key, and the method to execute as its value. However, the `DisplayHelp` command needs to reference itself from the `Map` of `Commands`. The `DisplayHelp` method, the `Commands` Map, and the `InterpCommand` code all looks like this:

```
let private DisplayHelp (shellState : ShellState) =
    printfn "Available commands: "
    
    Commands // <- This is where mutual recursive reference occurs
    |> Map.map (fun k _ -> printfn "%s" k)
    |> ignore
    
    shellState

let private Commands =
    [
        "exit", Exit
        "help", DisplayHelp // <- This is the other place where mutual reference recursion occurs
        "store", StoreItem
        "list", ListItems
    ]
    |> Map.ofList

let private InterpCommand (shellState : ShellState) =
    let nextState =
        match Commands.Keys.Contains shellState.Command with
        | true ->
            shellState
            |> Commands[shellState.Command]
        | false ->
            shellState
            |> DisplayUnrecognizedCommand
    // return
    nextState
    |> ResetStateInputs
```

As you can see, the mutual recursion happens between the `DisplayHelp` method and the `Commands` map. I was attempting to use the `and` keyword to mutually define these but it seems like bad practice. What is the correct pattern to use here, or is the problem itself solved in a completely different manner?

Comment: Pass the commands list to `DisplayHelp` as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of mutual recursion by using the approach suggested by @Fyodor Soikin, that it by abstracting concrete reference by introducing parameter for it. In our case - to abstract reference to `Commands` from function `DisplayHelp`:

```
let private DisplayHelp(shellState : ShellState, commands) = // introduce parameter commands
    printfn "Available commands: "
    commands
    |> Map.map(fun k _->printfn "%s" k)
    |> ignore
    shellState
    
let rec private Commands =
    [
        "exit", Exit
        "help", fun state -> DisplayHelp(state, Commands) // pass Commands to DisplayHelp as parameter 
        "store", StoreItem
        "list", ListItems
    ]
    |> Map.ofList
```

From theoretical standpoint it might also be interesting to eliminate recursion from `Commands` definition. As an option, it can be done by using [Fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). The idea is to introduce additional parameter (`f`) to target function (`createCommands`), which should be used instead of recursive calls. In this case it is required to wrap the target function (`createCommands`) into fixed-point combinator (`fix`). The function [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21646318/1719383) is recursive itself (at least in F# implementation) but it can be used universally to eliminate any kind of recursion in general way:

```
// Declare fixed point combinator
let rec fix' f = lazy f (fix' f)
let fix f = (fix' f).Value

let private DisplayHelp(shellState : ShellState, commands) =
    printfn "Available commands: "
    commands
    |> Map.map(fun k _->printfn "%s" k)
    |> ignore
    shellState
    
let private createCommands (f: Lazy<_>) () = // transform value to non-recursive function and add f parameter for self referncing
    [
        "exit", Exit
        "help", fun state -> DisplayHelp(state, f.Value ()) // call f function (unwrapped from lazy) insted of recursive call
        "store", StoreItem
        "list", ListItems
    ]
    |> Map.ofList

let Commands = fix createCommands () // wrap function with fixed point combinator and call it
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take @Fyodor Soikin 's comment but still ended up using some recursive definition because it cuts down on complexity and paves the way for more flexibility. @Gennadii Saltyshchak 's answer is really interesting, but after some thought, packing `ShellCommands` into the `ShellState` record paves the way to also keep track of something like a `ShellConfig` where certain commands can flip various config flags on and off, commands can be disabled, etc (this obviously asks that each `ShellCommand` be turned eventually into a record/object type of its own with text names and perhaps their own help info as well, moving in a *somewhat* more OOP paradigm). The code I ended up with *did not* avoid recursion, but it is still cleaner than what I was originally trying to carve out. Here's the code:

```
type private ShellCommand = ShellState -> ShellState
and private ShellState =
    {
        PromptInput: string
        Command: string
        Arguments: string list
        ItemsStored: string list
        Running: bool
        AvailableCommands: Map<string, ShellCommand>
    }
    with 
    static member init(availableCommands: Map<string, ShellCommand>) : ShellState =
        {
            PromptInput = ""
            Command = ""
            Arguments = []
            ItemsStored = []
            Running = true
            AvailableCommands = availableCommands
        }

/// ... snip ...

let private DisplayUnrecognizedCommand : ShellCommand = fun shellState ->
    eprintf $"Command not recognized: {shellState.Command}"
    shellState

let private DisplayHelp : ShellCommand = fun shellState ->
    printfn "Available commands: "

    shellState.AvailableCommands
    |> Map.map (fun k _ -> printfn "%s" k)
    |> ignore
    
    shellState

let private InterpCommand (shellState : ShellState) =
    let nextState =
        match shellState.AvailableCommands.Keys.Contains shellState.Command with
        | true ->
            shellState
            |> shellState.AvailableCommands[shellState.Command]
        | false ->
            shellState
            |> DisplayUnrecognizedCommand
    // return
    nextState
    |> ResetStateInputs


let private Prompt (shellState: ShellState) =
    printf "> "
    let input = Console.ReadLine().Trim()
    { shellState with 
        PromptInput = input }

let rec private Run (shellState : ShellState) =
    if(shellState.Running) then
        shellState
        |> Prompt
        |> ParseInput
        |> InterpCommand
        |> Run
    else
        ()

let private AvailableCommands =
    [
        "exit", Exit
        "help", DisplayHelp
        "store", StoreItem
        "list", ListItems
    ]
    |> Map.ofList

let StartShell () =
    Run(ShellState.init(AvailableCommands))
```

(However since I did not avoid recursion as I had asked in the original question, I'll accept the other answer as the right one :)